# TYPO3 - Extbase - Map foreign data (provided by API)

Tags: api, typo3, domain-driven-design, extbase

I want to use foreign data (provided by an external API) within an extbase extension. The data should be accessible by any kind of repository, providing the foreign objects as local models. There should not be any local database persistence layer for the foreign data in between.

Let’s take a „blog“ with posts as an example: I could implement a custom „PostRepository“ with „findAll()“ and „findByUid()“ methods, which query the API in behind and map the retrieved objects to local domain objects. But how can i use the benefits of extbase object mapping mechanism? I would like to be able to do something like:

```
PostController::showAction(Post $post)
```

What is necessary to get the argument mapping mechanism work for this (not locally persisted) data? Is this possible at all? Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Comment: Please add more details why a local copy of the external data is not an option. Otherwise you could use e.g. [External Data Import](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/external_import) for sync.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Because the data might change externally (typo3) as well as internally (crm/erp) I would like to prevent any „bidirectional synchronisation“ and related issues.

Comment: I can only recommend to have a look at the mentioned extension unless you add more details.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala The extension look great. But i am really interested in an approach without any local copy. Which further details do you need or what do i miss in my question?

Answer (score 1):

For mapping data to models, TYPO3 has its `DataMapper`.

A piece of explanation can be found in the [docs of blog-example](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/3-BlogExample/7-Paths-on-the-Data-Map.html#paths-on-the-data-map):

> The `DataMapper` object has the task to create an instance of the objects
> class for each tuple and “fill” this fresh instance with the data of the tuple.
> The DataMapper object also resolves all relations.

To make it less abstract, a bit of code:

```
public function mapProperties(): AnyModel
{
  $properties = [
    'uid' => 123,
    'pid' => 123,
    'firstname' => 'Alex',
    'lastname' => 'Kellner'
    'email' => 'my@email.org'
  ];
  $dataMapper = $this->objectManager->get(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::class);
  $anyModels = $dataMapper->map(AnyModel::class, [$properties]);
  return $anyModels[0];
}
```

(Source: https://gist.github.com/einpraegsam/679156ccd9fb1cb94af5f901519d89fc)

Comment: Simple mapping is described here, but it's certainly limited in options: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html